# Control time-series axis label and color in R stacked bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I'm trying to plot a stacked bar. Its work but still there are some function that I don't understand e.g, what xts do? Am I using all the library I've load?  Replacing the axis label, its work with original data, but not with melted data (data was melted for producing stacked bar, because I didn't find any other ways to produced stacked bar using data.frame) . I also want to  use monochrome color for this stacked bar. I try replacing 'fill = variable' to 'fill = c("orange", "blue", "green")' just to try, its not working. Kindly help.. Thank you..

```
library(ggplot2)
library(xts)
library(reshape2)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)
setwd("C:/Users/Hp/Documents/yr")
data1 <- read.csv("yr1983.csv", head = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data1$Date <- dmy(data1$Date)
#data1 <- xts(x = data1[,-1], order.by = data1[,1])

head(data1)
         Date Inland middle coastal
 1 1983-11-01    0.0    0.0     0.0
 2 1983-11-02    0.0    0.0     0.0
 3 1983-11-03   90.5   19.5    60.0
 4 1983-11-04   88.5   28.5    53.8
 5 1983-11-05   80.5   73.0   122.0
 6 1983-11-06  179.5  102.0   141.3

#plot stacked bar
data.m <- melt(data1,id.vars = "Date")
p1 <- ggplot(data.m, aes(x = Date, y = value,fill=variable)) + 
geom_bar(stat='identity')
p1

#try to rename the axis - error
  Rainfall_Intensity <- data1$value
  month <- data1$Date
  ggplot(data.m, aes(x = month, y = Rainfall_Intensity,fill= variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
  *Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (276): x, y, fill

  ggplot(data1, aes(month, y = Rainfall_Intensity,fill= variable)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
 *Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Date' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

look that:

```
Rainfall_Intensity <- data1$value
month <- data1$Date
```

The variables Rainfall_Intensity and month they not inside of the **data.m**. Therefore, when you use ggplot it generates the errors presented above. You must rename the variables:

```
rename(data.m,Rainfall_Intensity = value, month = Date)
```

And, after this, run your ggplot2.

Comment: function rename cant be found, does it need special package?

Comment: Its a function of dplyr

Answer (score 1):

`fill = variable` under `aes` is referring to the variable according to which the stacked bars are supposed to be separated. To change the colours of the stacked bars, you want to change fill under `geom_bar`

```
ggplot(data.m, aes(x = Date, y = value,fill=variable)) 
             + geom_bar(stat='identity', fill = c("orange", "blue", "green"))
```

You can refer to - http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/colour - for choosing colours.

Comment: link you provide should be beneficial for me... still try to figure it out.. I tried your ggplot then it comeout with Error in +geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = c("orange", "blue", "green")) : 
  invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: I'm using + scale_fill_manual(values = c("thistle4", "violet", "blue")) and its work.. Thank you for your hint..

Comment: I'm using + scale_fill_manual(values = c("thistle4", "violet", "blue")) and its work.. Thank you for your hint..

Answer (score 1):

`ggplot2` operates on entire data frames, so it expects that whatever names you use to map to aesthetics in `aes` are the bare column names from the data frame supplied to either the `data` param of the initial `ggplot` call, or a `data` param for a specific geom. Therefore, if you have a global variable called `date` and you call `ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = value))`, it will be looking for a column in `data` called `date`, and will throw an error if one isn't found.

If you need to rename columns in your data frame, you can do that lots of different ways, such as `names(data.m) <- c(...)` or `setNames(data.m, c(...))`.

But if all you need to do is change the axis labels, you can do that as part of building the plot. Either assign labels using `labs`, or assign a single label within the corresponding scale function.

Changing several labels at once with `labs` (I just guessed based on the data sample):

```r
library(tidyverse)

...

ggplot(data.m, aes(x = Date, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Rainfall intensity", fill = "Location", 
       title = "Rainfall intensity by location", 
       subtitle = "November 1983")
```

[image]

Changing just the x-axis label within a call to `scale_x_date`:

```r
ggplot(data.m, aes(x = Date, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_date(name = "Month")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-06-29 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).